# How to trace the missing pixels when using drawLine

Tags: qt, qt4, qpainter

We know that for drawing on an image in qt, qpainter is used. Recently, I used drawLine() function to draw whatever an user is scribbling. This was done by passing the lastPoint and currentPoint from the mouseMoveEvent to a custom function which implements drawLine(). I have passed the arguments for that custom function as given below:

```
void myPaint::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {  
qDebug() << event->pos();
   if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && scribbling) {
    pixelList.append(event->pos());
    drawLineTo(event->pos());
    lastPoint = event->pos();
   }
}
```

Now with the help of qDebug() I noticed that some pixels are missed while drawing but the drawing is precise. I looked up the source of qt-painting where I saw that drawLine() was calling drawLines() which was making use of qpainterPath to have a shape drawn on the image.

My question is that, is there anyway to track these "missed" pixels or any approach to find all the pixels which have been drawn?

Thanks!

```
void myPaint::drawLineTo(const QPoint &endPoint) {    
QPainter painter(image); //image is initialized in the constructor of myPaint
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, myPenWidth, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap,Qt::RoundJoin));
painter.drawLine(lastPoint, endPoint);
modified = true;
lastPoint = endPoint; //at the mousePressEvent, the event->pos() will be stored as
                      // lastPoint 
update();
}
```

Comment: what is drawLineTo? How do you know "pixels are missing"? and why do you want to bother with such things?

Comment: @UmNyobe, I have made the edit above which shows the drawLineTo definition
I came to know that the pixels are missing while drawing with the help of qDebug() in mouseMoveEvent(). You see, if we draw a straight line, then all the pixels in that line should be tracked right, but instead some were skipped and I believe that this is becasue the user->kernel and kernel->user switch which takes place while calling the painter engine to draw on the image.
I am bothering abt this because I am curious to know how drawLine() is adding pixels in between

Comment: What do you mean by missing pixels? What did you expect to get qith qDebug and what did you get?

Comment: @webclectic, I drew a straight line, say from (10,10) to (100,10) (not precisely straight but yeah, which looks like a straight line), and the pixels which were drawn were not continuous which I assume its because of the function-calling overhead as I said in my above comment. So instead of getting all the "drawn" pixels between (10,10) to (100,10), some were not tracked while mouseMoveEvent was occuring. Is there anyway to get all the "drawn" pixel values when we are scribbling on the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, don't draw in a `mouseEvent()`. Actually handling a mouseevent should be done as quick as possible. Also, it is not a good idea to look at the Qt source, it can be confusing. Rather assume that what Qt gives you work, and first try to answer "What I am doing wrong?". As I said drawing in a mouse event is definitely wrong.

Your description is really subjective, maybe an image of your output is better. Are you trying to emulate a pen (like in windows paint)? In this case do the mouse button has to be down ? is that the purpose of your variable `scribbling`?

There is more. following the documentation, [QMouseEvent::buttons()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html#buttons) always return a combination of all buttons for mouse move event. Which make sense : the mouse movements are independent of the buttons. It means

`if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)`

will always be true.

Let's assume you want to draw the path of your mouse when the left button is pressed. Then you use something like :

```
void myPaint::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
     scribbling = true;
     pixelList.clear();
}

void myPaint::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
     scribbling = false;
}

void myPaint::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {  
  if ( scribbling) {
    pixelList.append(event->pos());
  }
}

void myPaint::paintEvent(){
  QPainter painter(this)
  //some painting here
  if ( scribbling) {
     painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
     painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, myPenWidth, Qt::SolidLine, Qt::RoundCap,Qt::RoundJoin));
    // here draw your path
    // for example if your path can be made of lines, 
    // or you just put the points if they are close from each other
  }

  //other painting here
}
```

If after all of this you don't have a good rendering, try using float precision (slower), ie `QMouseEvent::posF()` instead of `QMouseEvent::pos()`.

**EDIT :** 
***"I want to know whether there is any way to calculate all the sub-pixels between any two pixels that we send as arguments to drawLine"***
Yes there is. I don't know why you need to do such thing but is really simple. A line can be characterized with the equation

```
   y = ax + b
```

Both of the endpoints of the line `p0 = (x0, y0)` and `p1 = (x1, y1)` satisfy this equation so you can easily find `a` and `b`. Now all you need to do is increment from `x0` to `x1` by the amount of
pixels you want (say 1), and to compute the corresponding `y` value, each time saving `point(x,y)`.

So will go over all of the points saved in `pixelList` and repeat this process for any two consecutive points.

Comment: For your information I haven't drawn in the mouseEvent and my paint application is similar to that of the Scribble in sample widget projects of Qt.
Also I have used the mouseEvents as you have described above, except that we dont need event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton condition check while scribbling.

Yet to try with the posF() instead of pos(). Let me see

Comment: yes but you are drawing onto an image... and you call update();

Comment: Finished trying with posF() of QMouseEvent. See, the rendering is good, but I want to know whether I can get all the pixel-values which are drawn?

Comment: It is supposed to be the color of your QPen. in this case blue.

Comment: Yes, it is blue in this case. I checked out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219827/qt-mouse-skipping-not-updating-every-pixel-mousemoveevent
The answer there was to use a drawLine between two sub-pixels. 
In my case, I want to know whether there is any way to calculate all the sub-pixels between any two pixels that we send as arguments to drawLine()?