# QGraphicsItem mouseMoveEvent too slow

Tags: qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicsitem

I'm handling a mouseMoveEvent for a QGraphicsPixmapItem in a QGraphicsScene, which works well, but when I move the mouse too quickly, it skips some pixels. A similar question was asked here, [Qt, Mouse skipping, not updating every pixel, mouseMoveEvent()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219827/qt-mouse-skipping-not-updating-every-pixel-mousemoveevent), but it was asked 9 years ago and I was wondering if anything improved since then.

How can I capture all the pixels?

Comment: Why do not you interpolate the points?

Comment: I logged the points in item::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *e) but it seems like the missing points weren't captured there either.

Comment: That is normal, understand that Qt has to handle many events at once so it will not register all mouse positions. 
In addition to the latency that you mention  you also have to add the latency that the OS generates when giving you the mouse data.

Comment: Is this a Qt issue then? And there is no workaround for it? I've seen applications able to capture quick mouse move events without a problem.

Comment: I have worked with several libraries and you always get the same effect, that is a problem of every program that handles many events at the same time. I am very curious about the programs that correctly capture the mouse, can you tell me any? And besides, how do you know he captures it correctly?

Comment: how do you know he captures it correctly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171367/discussion-between-alh-and-eyllanesc).